# mledist for Pareto distribution

Tags: r, distribution, pareto-chart

I'm trying to find a distr. by using mledist function. But every time i use it i find a error message:

```
[1] "Error in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,  : \n  non-finite finite-difference value [2]\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth, lower = lower,     upper = upper, ...): non-finite finite-difference value [2]>
```

The thing is that i know, "Alae" have a pareto distribution, but I can't understand where is my mistake. Please help:) This is my code

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(CASdatasets)
data(lossalae)
pertes<-lossalae
Alae <- pertes$ALAE   
Alae_par <- mledist(Alae, 'pareto',start=c(shape=5,scale=2))
```

TNX

Comment: I get a different error: "Error in mledist(Alae, "pareto", start = c(shape = 5, scale = 2)) : 
  The  dpareto  function must be defined"

Answer (score 0):

Given the origin of the CASdatasets is a Canadian insurance author, I'm guessing that the `dpareto`-function is supposed to come from pkg:`actuar`:

```
> library(actuar)

Attaching package: ‘actuar’

The following object is masked from ‘package:grDevices’:

    cm

> library(fitdistrplus)
> library(CASdatasets)
> data(lossalae)
> pertes<-lossalae
> Alae <- pertes$ALAE   
> Alae_par <- mledist(Alae, 'pareto',start=c(shape=5,scale=2))
Warning messages:
1: In dpareto(c(3806L, 5658L, 321L, 305L, 758L, 8768L, 1805L, 78L,  :
  NaNs produced
snipped 6 other warnings

> Alae_par
$estimate
       shape        scale 
    2.221351 15106.971534 

$convergence
[1] 0

$loglik
[1] -15413.45

$hessian
             shape         scale
shape 303.98838362 -3.083551e-02
scale  -0.03083551  3.637979e-06

$optim.function
[1] "optim"

$fix.arg
NULL
```